# How to read and write from shared memory to create an array QT

Tags: c++, qt

I tried the following:

**Write**

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
QBuffer buffer;
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
    QDataStream out(&buffer);
    out << a[5];
    int size = buffer.size();

    if (!sharedMemory.create(size)) {
        ui.label->setText(tr("Unable to create shared memory segment."));
        return;
    }
    sharedMemory.lock();
    char *to = (char*)sharedMemory.data();
    const char *from = buffer.data().data();
    memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMemory.size(), size));
    sharedMemory.unlock();
```

**Read**

```
sharedMemory.attach();
QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream in(&buffer);
    int a[5];
    //QImage image;
    QString fileName;
    int num;
    sharedMemory.lock();
    buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
    in >> a[5];
    sharedMemory.unlock();
```

But the way I thought was wrong.I do not know how to read and write is an array of characters and integers .

Comment: So, do you get any errors or it just doesn't work? Did you check if it actually sends anything to shared memory? I mean to check the `from` pointer and the `constData` it there is something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first real problem here is `a[5]`: the array `a` only has 5 items, so the 5th index is out of its bounds. To write and read the whole array you can 1) do it one item at a time; or 2) with a vector or list object such as `QVector`.

**1. As Array**

*Write:*

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&buffer);

//write item by item
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    out << a[i];
}

int size = buffer.size();
if (!sharedMemory.create(size)) {
    cout << "Unable to create shared memory segment: "<<sharedMemory.errorString().toStdString()<<endl;
    return;
}
sharedMemory.lock();
char *to = (char*)sharedMemory.data();
const char *from = buffer.data().data();
memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMemory.size(), size));
sharedMemory.unlock();
```

*Read:*

```
sharedMemory.attach();
QBuffer buffer;
QDataStream in(&buffer);

sharedMemory.lock();
buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

int len = sharedMemory.size()/sizeof(int);
int* a = new int[len];
for (int i=0; i< len; i++) {
    in >> a[i];
}
sharedMemory.unlock();
//delete a;
```

(Note: don't forget to delete `a` after usage.)

**2. As QVector**

*Write:*

```
QVector<int> vec;
vec << 1<<2<<3<<4<<5;

QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&buffer);

//write the vector object
out << vec;

int size = buffer.size();
if (!sharedMemory.create(size)) {
    cout << "Unable to create shared memory segment: "<<sharedMemory.errorString().toStdString()<<endl;
    return;
}
sharedMemory.lock();
char *to = (char*)sharedMemory.data();
const char *from = buffer.data().data();
memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMemory.size(), size));
sharedMemory.unlock();
```

*Read:*

```
sharedMemory.attach();
QBuffer buffer;
QDataStream in(&buffer);

sharedMemory.lock();
buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

QVector<int> vec;
in>>vec;
sharedMemory.unlock();
```